# Deleting one row super slow on Azure SQL, but cascade delete is normal

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

When I delete an entity, it executes instantly on local but it takes almost 20~30 seconds on Azure SQL. High CPU and IO usage is observed from Azure SQL.

But if I delete the parent of the entity, (and the entity is cascade deleted) there is no problem. both local and Azure SQL executes the parent delete query instantly.

Is there a reason for this situation that just deleting a child is super slow but deleting whole children by cascade delete is normal?

Comment: Impossible to truly answer this without seeing at least the execution plan. Better still would be to see the plan and your structure. Without that, I can only make really vague guesses.

Comment: Can you share a repro